# solr optional query fields exempt from mm criteria

Tags: solr

I have 5 query fields in my search query and I have fairly complicated mm parameter which starts with 3 meaning minimum 3 (in the case of at least 3 search terms) or the number of search terms (in the case of less than three search terms) matches are needed. I want one particular query field specified in the qf field out of the 5 to be exempt from the mentioned matching criteria. In other words, I want it to be used not for determining which documents should be matched but only for ranking the match results. Is this possible?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. Which fields are for matching and which for ranking? You may need to rephrase it.

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch, I rephrased it. Could you tell me what you didn't understand clearly?

Comment: Could you maybe provide example data, and the query for that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a field is not used for matching, it probably should not appear in that list. If you want to use it afterwards to change the ranking, you could experiment with boost queries or with [Query Re-Ranking](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Query+Re-Ranking).